# JSON Schema (or IntelliJ plugin) for JSON object required by Elasticsearch Create Index API

Tags: elasticsearch, intellij-idea, configuration, jsonschema, intellij-plugin

Is there an available **[JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/)** for the request object required by **Elasticsearch [Create Index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html)**?

I didn't find any schema in the [JSON Schema Store](https://www.schemastore.org/json/).

I want to validate the JSON object in IntelliJ IDEA and have the assisted edit.

Alternatively, is there any IntelliJ plugin with built-in support for editing these files? I did not find the support in any of the existing `Elasticsearch*` plugins.

> You can use the create index API to add a new index to an Elasticsearch cluster. When creating an index, you can specify the following:
>
> - Settings for the index
> - Mappings for fields in the index
> - Index aliases

The JSON object to create Elasticsearch index looks like this:

```json
{
  "settings": {
    ...
  },
  "mappings": {
    ...
  },
  "aliases": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a [global JSON schema](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/main/rest-api-spec/src/main/resources/schema.json) for all API requests, but without the body. There's an [ongoing effort](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25152), though. However, there are [Typescript definitions](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-specification/tree/main/specification/indices/create) for all operations, if that helps. Here is the one for [the create index API](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-specification/blob/main/specification/indices/create/IndicesCreateRequest.ts).

Comment: @Val We need to keep the index JSON in GIT to track the changes.

Comment: Yes, but you can certainly generate a JSON schema out of those Typescript files: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-json-schema

Comment: @Val I tried but cannot make it working. I am in the folder `/workspace/elasticsearch-specification/specification`, try running `../../node_modules/.bin/typescript-json-schema tsconfig.json *` or `../../node_modules/.bin/typescript-json-schema tsconfig.json IndicesCreateRequest` but always get error `type <something> not found`. (I know virtually nothing about TS or JS, I work normally with Java.)